# Linux login issues/questions. Current command line ends with: "~$"

Tags: login

My kitty sat on the keyboard for my laptop and caused a weird issue on the monitor.

I have been trying many things to fix the problem, and now I'm locked out.
I am at the login screen and my username and password are working I think. The current command line ends with: ~$
Directly above this command line is the "Last login", which lists my login earlier today: "(today's date and time) on ttyl".

What am I to put after the "~$"? I desperately need to get back into my computer!

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Just to clarify, you're logged in via the command-line interface, but you want to get back to a graphical interface?  If so, the easiest option might simply be to type `sudo reboot`.

Comment: try pressing Alt+F1 (or Alt+F2 or +F3…) first. Your cat might just have switched from your graphical interface to a text console!

Comment: `$` refers to your [Shell Prompt](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Shell_Prompt) and `~` refers to your home directory.  Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 or F2 as Marcus suggests should fix the issue as most distributions set the DM service to start on the primary terminal(F1).  BTW, you are "in your computer" and distibutions didn't always have an X Server running.

Comment: These suggestions are very much appreciated! Mr. Timmy made the screen split with the mouse area magnified...and I was needing to fix that. My attempts to fix that are what brought me to the current situation of being unable to login to the graphic interface. The first suggestion to type "sudo reboot " leads to the next prompt for "[sudo] password for christine".  I don't know what my sudo password is but I put my regular password in again >enter>screen goes black with blinking cursor, the green Linux emblem comes up, and then back to the original login screen...?

Comment: In summary,  I'm still stuck. I feel like these suggestions got me further than any other help I found thus far and you guys are so great for helping me...I am going to run some errands but I'll check back in later today.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you said what Linux distro you are running. If your GUI is Gnome then you can probably start it with: `sudo systemctl start gdm3`, then input your password if requested. Different GUIs (KDM, XFCE...) have different start commands. If `gdm3` does not work, try `display-manager`.